# Implementing Search box in bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I need to have a search box besides dropdown

[image: search box]

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class='col-sm-3'>
  <h2>Balances & History</h2>
</div>
<div class='col-sm-6'>
</div>
<div class='col-xs-2'>
  <select class="form-control">
<option value="">Select</option>
</select>
</div>
```

Comment: I need same background also for search box

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('.select2').select2();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/js/select2.min.js"></script>


<div class='col-sm-3'>
    <h2>Balances & History</h2>
    </div>
    <div class='col-sm-6'>
    </div>
    <div class='col-xs-2'>
        <select class="form-control select2">
            <option value="">Select</option>
               <option value="">Select 1234</option>
                  <option value="">Select  653</option>
                     <option value="">Select dfgd</option>
          </select>
    </div>
```

Comment: I dont need js   , need only static now. I am wrking with typescript.

Comment: @Aditya What you mean by static. Does that mean that you don't need to perform search inside the select box?

Comment: I dont need functionality, just need html,css for it.  As I am working with angular I will need functionality later.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Angular then I suggest to use Angular material design instead of bootstrap. We are currently developing angular based application. Material design provides a good UI and it has lot of examples.

Refer to the below example for a static drop down page.

https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/autocomplete

Comment: buddy, but I am not using angular js,   its Angular4

Comment: Even I used Angular 4 and implemented the search functionality like what you need. Do you know the difference between angular js and angular 4/5

Comment: I have edited code and now want to adjust my search box size same as dropdown